# Does Ruby have a this.var = "somevalue" functionality?

Tags: ruby

I'm writing my first application in Ruby and I had a question.

Here is a sample:

```
 class SomeClass
    def initialize(host)
       @host = host
    end
end
```

How can I change the value of @host within another method? I have tried using 
`self.host = "somenewvalue"` but that doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use attr_accessor:

```
    class SomeClass
    attr_accessor :host
    def initialize(host)
       @host = host
    end
    end
```

or attr_reader and attr_writer to define methods host(getter) and host=(setter) separately.

**UPD**: got it wrong. You can access instance variables by adding @ in front of the variable name. So @host="someothervalue" inside an instance method will work fine.

Answer (score 1):

That's because `self.host = 'somenewvalue'` is actually calling the `host=` metod on `self` with `'somenewvalue'` as argument. Since the method is not defined, an error will be raised.

To solve the problem, simply define the method:

```
def host=(new_host)
  @host = new_host.to_s
end
```

You can also write `attr_writer :host`, which defines a method similar to the above. `attr_accessor` defines both reader and writer methods.